# The SQL Table is not being created from the schema-mysql.sql file

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am trying to make an application using **Spring Boot** and **JDBC**.

However, the creation of the Table is not getting initiated.

I have created a `schema-mysql.sql` file to have the table created.

The `schema-mysql.sql` file is as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Pirate;

CREATE TABLE Pirate (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

Application properties:

```
server.port=8081
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=default
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Repository used to interact with the Database:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class PirateRepository extends JdbcDaoSupport {
    
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;
    
    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize() {
        setDataSource(dataSource);
    }
    
    
    public void insertPirate(Pirate pirate)
    {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Pirate "+"(Name,Email) VALUES (?,?)";
        getJdbcTemplate().update(sql,new Object[] {pirate.getName(),pirate.getEmail()});
    }
    
    public List<Pirate> getAllPirates(){
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Pirate";
        List<Map<String,Object>> rows = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql);
        List<Pirate> result = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for(Map<String, Object> row:rows) {
            Pirate pirate = new Pirate();
            pirate.setId((Integer)row.get("id"));
            pirate.setName((String)row.get("Name"));
            pirate.setEmail((String)row.get("Email"));
            result.add(pirate);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Can you please tell me what I am missing, due to the table not being initiated? According to the program question, no Jpa or Crud Repository can be used.

Comment: I noted that there's an extra `"` at the end of the line where `INSERT INTO` is located. Is that your actual code?

Comment: Can you try defining `spring.datasource.platform=mysql` onto your properties file? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc

Comment: @goldthelocks You should create an answer. That way the question will be marked as answered, you'll earn reputation and people with the same problem will see your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @Brhaka! Will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define `spring.datasource.platform=mysql` onto your properties file.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc